# Saving and restoring state of elements in dialog based MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc

I am writing simple C++ dialog based MFC application. It has several inputs, checkboxes, time selects. As a part of it's functionality it should have Save and Load buttons which would save/restore state of those elements. For example text in input, if some elements are disabled or not, their values.

The question is - what is the right approach to do it? The most simple and direct one would be to save values in a specific order (say `text1,text2,checkbox1_state,time_select1`) and then in the same order restore them one by one.

Are there other options? I don't want to use some other libraries (saw Boost is mentioned frequently in terms of serialization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MFC has a [CArchive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/caz3zy5s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class you could consider using for serialization of controls or dialogs. You could also roll your own serialization with file streams.

Comment: Thank you. It makes perfect sense for separate class with all it's properties. MSDN also have example on making class serializable. But do I have such class in my case? Bunch of variables and states which somehow lead back to controls?

Comment: Yes, it should meet your needs. In your shoes I might make a container class to hold the controls and then add serialization to that so all of the states and values could be saved/loaded from one place.